# What could cause a returning function to crash? C++

Tags: c++, function, crash, return, void

So I have been debugging this error for hours now. I writing a program using Ogre3d relevant only because it doesn't load symbols so it doesn't let me stack trace which made finding the location of the crash even harder. So, write before I call a specific function I print out "Starting" then I call the function and immediately after I print "Stopping". Throughout the function I print out letters A-F where F is printed right before the function returns (one line above the last '}') The weird thing is when the crash occurs it is after the 'F' is printed but there is no 'Stopping'. Does this mean that the crash is happening in between somewhere? The only thing I can think of is something going wrong during the deallocation of some of the memory allocated during the function. I've never had anything happen like this, I will keep checking to make sure it's going wrong where I think it is.

Comment: All kinds of things. Why not show the relevant code?

Comment: Could be anything -- if you e.g. messed up stack via stray pointer -- but it sounds like bug that manifests via a destructor being called. Try to reproduce the problem in a smallest possible but complete program. Post the code (if the process didn't uncover the bug). Cheers,

Comment: Can't tell you anything if you don't post the code.

Comment: The code posted would have been a lot of copy/pasting and less relevant. But I believe I found the problem as one of the answers listed below said.

Comment: If you use stdio for tracking when something happens then remember to call `fflush()` every time you write a log message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the times when something weird and un-understandable happens, it's because of something else.

You could have some [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) in your code (even in a place far away from that function) pointing to some *random* memory cells.

You might have used such dangling pointer, and it might have resulted in overwriting some memory cells you need. The result of this is that you changed the behavior of your program by changing some variable defined elsewhere, some constants, or even some code!

I'd suggest you to debug your application using some tool able to check and report erroneous memory accesses, like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

---

Anyway if you are able to localize the source of your crash and to write a really small piece of code that will crash post it here -- it could be just a simple error in your function, although it sounds unlikely, from your description.

Comment: Like I mentioned below apparently I was writing in memory outside of an indexed array (I allocated space for 100 and was writing to indices over that) but this wasn't causing the crashes, it was coming out of that I'm guessing I messed up the stack outside of that frame and when it returned everything was messed up. I'm just confused on why it allowed me to play with that data.

Comment: C++ is not a managed language: the compiler tries to statically check anything it can, but it won't run any run-time checks. Your error happens at runtime (statically analyzing your code, the compiler cannot say whether you'll access only the _right_ array elements or not). Valgrind is a tool that will check what is going on at run-time, it's basically doing part of what the virtual machine for a managed language do.

Comment: Yeah, I think in the past when I accessed memory outside of a location I would get a seg fault because the memory accessed was not in that allocated for my program I guess because in my years programming I don't remember creating a non-heap based array inside a function. Maybe that was it.

Answer (score 3):

This *probably* means that the error is happening when the function returns and some destructor is firing.  Chances are that you have some destructor trying to free memory it doesn't own, or writing off the end of some buffer in a log, etc.

Another possibility to be aware of might come up if you aren't flushing the output stream.  It's possible that "Stopping" is getting printed, but is being buffered before hitting `stdout`.  Make sure to check for this, since if that's what's going on you'll be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I found what it was, it was extremely weird still. I was allocating space for an array (of size 100) however I was modifying values that were indexed over 100. The weird part was, this wasn't the problem I was able to do this. I don't know if it was the deallocation or more specifically the fact that I wrote over memory outside the frame register (I'm guessing) and when it returned the memory was jumbled and incorrect.

Comment: @JeanOTF- If that's the case you probably overwrote some data in the footer of the allocated block.  When the memory allocator tried to reclaim it, it probably caused the crash because it expected to find some sort of internal data (say, a pointer to the next block) but instead found garbage.  This happens all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out that my function was not returning anything when the signature expected a return type of std::shared_ptr, even though I was not using the return anywhere.

The function had the following signature:

```
std::shared_ptr<blDataNode> blConditionBasedDataSelectionUI::selectData(std::shared_ptr<blDataNode> inputData)
{
    // My error was due to the function
    // not returning anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and it turned out I forgot to init my vector before appending new items, which cause error when my function was comparing the vector with other list.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> lefteyeCV;
void Init() {
    // I need to add "lefteyeCV.clear();" here!
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        lefteyeCV.push_back(cv::Point(0, 0));
    }
}

// the following comparison will crash after "return 0" 
// because cl_ is of size 8, but if I run "Init()" twice, lefteyeCV.size() = 16
// then the comparison is out of range.
int irisTrack(){
    for (int i = 0; i < lefteyeCV.size(); i++) {
        cl_[i] = cv::Point(lefteyeCV[order[i]].x - leftRect.x, lefteyeCV[order[i]].y - leftRect.y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What's confusing is that, I'm using Xcode and the app crash right after "return 0" with the indecipherable message "thread 13: signal SIGABRT". However, using Visual Studio instead showed me the line where index is out of range.